IntelliJ Debugger Controls Greyed Out
I am trying to debug the built in tests of an MVN project in IntelliJ.
In the IntelliJ terminal I am issuing this build command:
mvnDebug clean install -U

Then I am pressing the debug button which takes me to the debug interface with controls greyed out.

This is my debug config - i have a module set, but I unset it for the sake of the screen shot

I tried restarting IntelliJ and killing any lingering processes.  I am Windows 11 and IntelliJ 2024
Any ideas on why my debug controls are greyed out?

Why do you try to debug Maven? If you want to debug the tests your project has you can execute the tests directly from your IDE....
